# Download file without displaying URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, excel, amazon-s3

### Story

I had anchor tags showing filenames, that when clicked used to download the file from S3 url. My client now requires me to hide url and not show it while downloading the file, and to use unique name on S3 and not readable file name. On download, the filename needs to be changed to the readable file name specified on upload.

### Requirements

There are 2 requirements

1. Change filename on download.
2. Hide file url from Front End - View.

### Efforts

**Effort-1: Using anchor tag**

Simplest solution was to create a temp anchor tag and use download attribute in that anchor tag.

```
<a id="2135"></a>
<script>
function download(event) {
    var fileData = getFileData(event);
    var tempAnch = $('a').attr({href: fileData.url, download: fileData.name});
    tempAnch.click();
    tempAnch.remove();
};
</script>
```

This downloads the file but doesn't change the name for some reasons. I couldn't solve it after many alterations.

**Effort-2: Using Ajax approach**

Now i tried downloading file content on JS side and save it to file.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: fileData.url,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(msg) {
            var blob = new Blob([msg],
                    {type: fileData.mimeType});
            saveAs(blob, fileData.name);
        }
    });
```

Now this code saves file with required name, and content is same for text file. But for Excel file or xlsx file the downloaded file is corrupted.

Is there any possible solution to download xlsx, csv, txt or zip file **without** showing URL to user and **changing** filename on download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ridiculousness of this requirement notwithstanding, here's how you tell the browser what to call the file it's downloading when the file is saved locally: you need S3 to add this response header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="the-desired-name.ext"
```

This can be done in 2 ways:

**Option 1.**

When you upload the file to S3, send that header.  S3 will return it with each download, and the browser will use that filename.

**Option 2.**

In your signed URL, tell S3 to add this header to the response.  This will add `&response-content-disposition=attac...` to the signed URL and S3 will see this and add the needed response header.

How you do this depends on what you're using to generate the pre-signed URL (i.e. which SDK, or if you wrote your own, as I did).

Additionally, when generating a pre-signed URL, there's a little-known feature that allows you to identify who you gave the signed URL to, right in the URL.  Since signed URLs cannot be altered or tampered with without completely invalidating the URL, a user is discouraged from "sharing" URLs they may discover because the URL identifies them.  :)  How is this done?  You add `x-amz-meta-{anything}={anything-else}` to the URL before signing. Example: `...&x-amz-meta-downloaded-by=michael-sqlbot&...`. The part of S3 that validates the URL will require these parameters to be present so that the URL will match the signature, but the part of S3 that actually returns what is being downloaded... disregards it.

Of course... if you're not using pre-signed URLs, then that is the *real* problem you have... and hiding the URL is just an attempt to solve the wrong problem.  Any minimally-sophisticated user can determine the URL and I would assert that there is no possible genuine security benefit to be achieved by trying to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working like that. You download something, the requesting client knows where it comes from. If you want to make the link usable only one time or for a specific person, then you need to stream it through your application server.

The only other solution would be to create users/permissions on S3 level, but even then the URL would be shown at some point.

I would not recommend to change the file name on each download though.

That said, install your own webserver, create an key for the download and let the user call your URL instead. On request you can deliver the file and invalidate the key.

Just be aware, that if a download takes a long while to complete, the resource on your webserver is blocked usually. Cheap PHP hosting with in example 1&1 want work for more than 10 concurrent users (I tried :-))

Comment: i am not changing file name on each download. Its just that file saved on s3 has unqiue random name. So when it is downloaded it should be changed back to the same old name.

Comment: If it is a single download for a single upload, you can try to use the S3 SDK to change the filename. Please look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html If you are working with it, please check on the security issues here which may raise. However, I still believe you should hide everything of this behind your own server. If not possible, check the JS SDK for renaming features.

Comment: use a cname for your domain bind that cname to your s3 bucket. no need to hide anything.